# How do I change the email address of an account created by AWS Control Tower

Tags: amazon-web-services

Let's say I created an account (including SSO) with email something+old@gmail.com using the Control Tower (CT) management account.
Then I needed to change the address of this account to be something+new@gmail.com.

I followed this user guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/change-account-email.html

I am up to step 5. At this stage, I can log in as root user using something+new@gmail.com, but this email isn't recognised at the SSO login portal. The portal still recognises and lets me log in as something+old@gmail.com.

However when I log in as the management user, I can see under CT and AWS organisations that it says something+new@gmail.com.

Step 5 mentions "Update the provisioned product in AWS Service Catalog using the account's previous email address" - I don't know what this means.

What else do I need to do so that I can log in at the SSO portal using something+new@gmail.com?

Comment: The user guide has already changed since your post but I wanted to ask how long did it take for AWS Control Tower to see the new root mail address? I have the problem that I can't update the AWS Service Catalog because in AWS Control Tower the old mail is still referenced.

Comment: @Shamshiel It was a while back so my memory isn't great, but I feel like it took around a week.